# How to see what's on SQL server CE database

Tags: sql-server

I have created a database in SQL server Compact Edition.
I tried to attach it in SQL server
management Express, but it did not work.
Could anyone tell me how to see the data that I 
saved using my VB.net code, as we can
see in Access.
When I load SSME, it asked for which server to 
connect with.  But my database is not saved on any server.
Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select SQL Server Compact Edition in the dropdown list when you start SSMS.

If you don't see it there, [install SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6053c6f8-82c8-479c-b25b-9aca13141c9e&displaylang=en).

Comment: Does it come where it gives list of servers?

Comment: Thanks
I will check it tomorrow and advise you if I find it.

Comment: Hi,I already have this installed but I donot see Connect To dialog

Comment: I have found it but it is greyed out, I can't change it